# returning a stringfromdate method

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

So here's some code that I'm having trouble with:

```
//format the date to a string for echoing it
    NSDateFormatter* formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formattedDate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle]; //now myFormatted is set to a long style
    NSString* dateForOutput = [formattedDate stringFromDate:self.datePickerOutlet.date];
    //also now need to set the "you began on" text to the newly chosen date
    [self.startDate setText:@"You started on: %@", dateForOutput];
```

The error that is given is: "Too Many Arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2"

I don't see why it's saying that I'm trying to pass in two methods. 
I tried to do the following in case I was being stupid but it still gave me an error:

```
//format the date to a string for echoing it
NSDateFormatter* formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formattedDate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle]; //now myFormatted is set to a long style
NSString* dateForOutput = [formattedDate stringFromDate:self.datePickerOutlet.date];
//also now need to set the "you began on" text to the newly chosen date
NSString *foobar = @"You started on: %@", dateForOutput;
[self.startDate setText:foobar];
```

Error given: "Interface type cannot be statically allocated"

Frankly I have no idea why it's giving me this error... some help would be greatly appreciated.
It's probably just something small that I'm just not seeing for some reason =/

cheers,
Matt

Comment: did u create Property for Date Picker and UIlabel..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the line

```
[self.startDate setText:@"You started on: %@", dateForOutput];
```

in the first block of code you have given, try the following line

```
[self.startDate setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You started on: %@", dateForOutput]];
```

But it is better to go with the second statements,

```
NSString *foobar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You started on: %@", dateForOutput];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are doing things in wrong way

You should do the Things in this way

```
NSDate* myDate=[NSDate new];

NSDateFormatter* formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formattedDate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

//now myFormatted is set to a long style

// here i just passed the current date

```
NSString* dateForOutput = [formattedDate stringFromDate:myDate];

//also now need to set the "you began on" text to the newly chosen date

NSString *foobar = @"You started on:";
```

//Now you can append The String

//this is the way you can append the string ..

```
foobar= [foobar  stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",dateForOutput];

[self.startDate setText:foobar];
```